# Scroll to matching text in textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, textarea, match, visible

I've got a large block of text in a textarea and I'd like to have my Javascript scroll the textarea to the location where I've found the matching text so that it's now visible within the textarea. I've figured out how to count the lines of text and calculate the line number of the matching text, but I can't quite figure out how to translate that information into making the textarea scroll to the located text.

```
function findLrec(lid) { 
     var pText = document.myform.niceLrecs.value; 
     var sCrit = "Lrec "; sCrit += lid; 
     var lrecBegin = pText.search(sCrit) 
     var lrecFound = pText.substring(lrecBegin+4,pText.length); 
     var lrecEnd = lrecFound.search("Lrec"); 
     if (lrecEnd < 0) lrecEnd = lrecFound.length; 
     lrecEnd = lrecBegin + lrecEnd + 4; 
     var niceLrecs = document.getElementById('TITLE'); 
     var lrecLineLoc = pText.substr(0,lrecBegin).split("\n").length; 
     var rat1 = pText.split(/\r*\n/).length; 
     if (rat1 < 1) rat1 = 1; 
     rat1 = lrecLineLoc/rat1; 
     niceLrecs.scrollTop = niceLrecs.scrollHeight*rat1-16;
}
```

Comment: please post your code relevant to your question

Comment: My apologies. I figured out what I was doing wrong. This is my result:

Comment: function findLrec(lid) {
 var pText = document.myform.niceLrecs.value;
 var sCrit = "Lrec ";
 sCrit += lid;
 var lrecBegin = pText.search(sCrit)
 var lrecFound = pText.substring(lrecBegin+4,pText.length);
 var lrecEnd = lrecFound.search("Lrec");
 if (lrecEnd < 0) lrecEnd = lrecFound.length;
 lrecEnd = lrecBegin + lrecEnd + 4;
 var niceLrecs = document.getElementById('TITLE');
 var lrecLineLoc = pText.substr(0,lrecBegin).split("\n").length;
 var rat1 = pText.split(/\r*\n/).length;
 if (rat1 < 1) rat1 = 1;
 rat1 = lrecLineLoc/rat1;
 niceLrecs.scrollTop = niceLrecs.scrollHeight*rat1-16;
}

Comment: I don't know how to make the posted code look like code, sorry